# Order a column in pbi matriz

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I would like to know if it´s possible to order a column in a pbi matrix by your own criteria. In my case i have this matrix:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OvfQQ.png)
and i would like to order like:
-Transport expenses on Sales
-Sales
-Transport expenses on purchases

Can someone help me?

Thanks in advance!

---

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.